# GPG with triple pipe and keyfile

Tags: linux, bash, shell, encryption, gnupg

I want to tar, compress with xz and then encrypt symmetrically with gpg using a key file.
I could to this with a for loop, but would rather like to do it by piping.

I tried the following, but it didn't work because of "Ambiguous input redirect":

```
tar cvf /home/user/backupdir | xz -1 | gpg -c --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --yes --symmetric --cipher-algo TWOFISH --digest-algo SHA512 -o backupdir.tar.xz.gpg < keyfile
```

Could someone help me maybe out with that, encryption and decryption by piping?

Thank you!

Comment: your tar does not support the --xz option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically doing:

```
tar | xz | gpg <file
```

In this chain you tell gpg to get input both from file and from the previous command.

There is only one STDIN you cannot read from two sources.

The man page gives a few solutions:

```
   --passphrase-fd n
          Read the passphrase from file descriptor n. Only the first line will
          be  read  from file descriptor n. If you use 0 for n, the passphrase
          will be read  from  STDIN.  This  can  only  be  used  if  only  one
          passphrase  is  supplied.  Note that this passphrase is only used if
          the option --batch has also been given.  This is different from gpg.

   --passphrase-file file
          Read the passphrase from file file. Only the first line will be read
          from file file. This can only be used if only one passphrase is sup‐
          plied. Obviously, a passphrase stored in a file is  of  questionable
          security if other users can read this file. Don't use this option if
          you can avoid it.  Note that this passphrase is  only  used  if  the
          option --batch has also been given.  This is different from gpg.

   --passphrase string
          Use  string  as  the  passphrase.  This can only be used if only one
          passphrase is supplied. Obviously,  this  is  of  very  questionable
          security  on  a  multi-user system. Don't use this option if you can
          avoid it.  Note that this passphrase is  only  used  if  the  option
          --batch has also been given.  This is different from gpg.
```

Since you already have the passphrase in a file, the second option looks good for you.

If the second option is not available or not working at your gpg version, you can use the first option instead:

```
gpg --passphrase-fd 3 3<keyfile
```

In this case gpg will get the data on STDIN and the keyfile on file descriptor 3.

Comment: Be aware that the `--passphrase-file` option only works when you also use `--batch`. I missed that and kept wondering why it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

For these cases exist named or anonymous pipes. Your command line also has multiple design flaws.

1) Read the manpage carefully. The -c and --symmetric flags from gpg do the same.

2) gpg uses compression as standard, so there are two compression schemes in your command line. Remove xz or use the -z 0 flag from gpg.

3) The --cipher-algo and --digest-algo flags, didn't do what you think, and will be useless here. They are only exist for message encryption. Use the --s2k-* flags instead for symmetric encryption.

Example:

```
KEY="secret" or KEY="$(cat /path/to/keyfile)"
tar -cvf - /home/user/backupdir | gpg --yes --batch --symmetric --passphrase-file <(echo "$KEY") --s2k-cipher-algo twofish --s2k-digest-algo sha512 -o backupdir.tar.gpg
```

The <(....) is called anonymous pipe, and the result between the (....) will be an file descriptor (mostly /dev/fd/63), that contains your passphrase. This file descriptor only exists for the lifetime of gpg, and only gpg can read or write from him at once. Also you command line will always show /dev/fd/63 in ps, top or /proc/PID/cmdline, and never the original passphrase. So it's an secure way to hand over a passphrase to processes, who can't read them from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

gpg gets its encrypted data from stdin, in your case, but you also specify that the passphrase comes from stdin, by `--passphrase-fd 0`. This will confuse gpg.

Maybe `cat` the keyfile to another file-descriptor (say 3), using `cat keyfile > &3` at the beginning, and use `--passphrase-fd 3` instead.

Comment: You could do `gpg --passphrase-fd 3 3<keyfile` but `gpg --passphrase-file keyfile` is probably the easier way.

Comment: The online man page didn't mention the --passphrase-file option, hence the workaround.

Comment: Windows7/cygwin/bash4.4.12 this works: cat data | gpg --passphrase-fd 3 3<<<"passphrase"  ...